# Relative layout, mispositioning of images on on different phones

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-relativelayout, drag

I am developing an android project of dragging and dropping images, using Relative Layout.

The problem here is, the images are sitting in position as expected when I test it on my Galaxy Grand phone, but if I test the same project on my Galaxy Nexus, the images appears to be mispositioned on the screen. Please check out the screen shots below:
1)galaxy nexus
2)galaxy grand screen shots and help me out.

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#3B5998" >

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagebackgroundofearth"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagered" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewunderleft"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagered" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewunderright"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imageorange" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewabove"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:src="@drawable/earth" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reload"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:text="Reload" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please show you current code.

Comment: there are so many things that can cause that.  We would have to see your layout files and maybe your code to figure it out.

Comment: @HalR, Emil Adz : I have added the XML code. Please check! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few small changes like this might be what you are looking for:

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:visibility="gone" />


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagebackgroundofearth"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagered" />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewunderleft"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagered" />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewunderright"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imageorange" />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewabove"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/earth" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/reload"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:text="Reload" />
```

If you make the two bottom views both measured from their respective side, they'll always match each other--sometimes a little closer, sometimes a little farther.  You could also make them relative to the center, too, if you prefer that.

I wasn't sure what you were trying to do with the earth.  If you expect them to line up, you'd best make them have the same alignment.  Also, you were using some sp's where I think you meant dp's.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks this works. Used the same code in XML and also I had to change one line programmatically. It started working fine.